# Supporting multiple screens without smartphones

Tags: android, android-compatibility, android-screen-support

I already read the http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

My question is, how can I filter on Google Play only for Galaxy Tab 7.0 (Android 2.2) or higher?

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I actually did that, but it's looks like that great phones like Galaxy S2 or XPeria Arc has "large" screens so this app will be available for those too. How can I filter that?

Comment: I think (but don't recall exactly) there is a way to configure it when you upload an apk to the market to target specific devices rather than screen sizes. I think you'd need something like that instead of adding it to your manifest. Are you trying to limit it specifically to that device only? If so may I ask why?

Comment: There are several "smartphones" that the manufacturers have categorized as `-large`. Unless you can state the common characteristic of such devices that causes you to not want your app on them, we cannot hope to help you filter them out as a category.

Answer (score 2):

After uploading to Google play, you can manually filter out the extra devices that you don't to support.

This [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=go&answer=1286017) has extra information on this subject.